# Django-registration - no module named simple error

Tags: django, django-registration

I've found that if you use version 1.5 of Django that the django-registration module breaks since in the latest dev version of django, the simple.py class has been removed.

Comment: That can help you -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781853/django-registration-no-module-named-simple/15783683#15783683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration

cd django-registration
setup.py install
```

or

```
pip install /path/to/local/clone/django-registration
```

If you don't have hg you can download the project from this link:

[django-registration snapshot](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/get/b3c41b3c7f50.zip)

Comment: For me much better seems to use `pip install -r requirements.txt` and add a line into .txt: `hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/downloads/django-registration-0.8.tar.gz` than cloning it into current folder. This way it will clone to virtual environment or / if you do not use **virtualenv** tool.

Comment: please explain why it didn't work for you? I added a manual download link.