# django-registration No module named simple

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm trying to install django-registration on my project using this tutorial:
http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/
but I get this error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named simple
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named simple
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\backends\default\urls.py in <module>, line 22
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Fabrizio\\Desktop\\django\\test\\gym',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 3 Apr 2013 09:39:44 +0200
```

I found some answers here but I was not able to fully understand the solution, could you please explain me how to solve it? thank you.

Comment: Can you post the content of urls.py?

Comment: @Siva   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The download link in that tutorial is to an old version of django-registration, which is not compatible with Django 1.5. You should check out the latest version directly from bitbucket and follow the instructions there.

Comment: I checked and downloaded the latest one that should be 0.8 right?

Comment: No. I said, the downloads are old. You need to *check out* the latest code if you're using Django 1.5.

Comment: Could you please give me a working link at the correct release? how to remove the oldest one? thank you

Comment: Press the "Clone" button at the top of the page. If you don't know how to clone a repo in git or mercurial, you should learn in any case.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Roseman, I downloaded the latest one from here: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/get/v0.8.zip
installed and it's working.

Comment: maybe `django-registration2` ? I've just installed it instead `django-registration` because `yolk -V django-registration` gives only `django-registration 0.8` which is not compatible with Django==1.5.1